# Populating Factory using Metaclasses in Python

Tags: python, factory-pattern, metaclass

Obviously, registering classes in Python is a major use-case for metaclasses.  In this case, I've got a serialization module that currently uses dynamic imports to create classes and I'd prefer to replace that with a factory pattern.

So basically, it does this:

```
data = #(Generic class based on serial data)
moduleName = data.getModule()
className = data.getClass()
aModule = __import__(moduleName)
aClass = getattr(aModule, className)
```

But I want it to do this:

```
data = #(Generic class based on serial data)
classKey = data.getFactoryKey()
aClass = factory.getClass(classKey)
```

However, there's a hitch: If I make the factory rely on metaclasses, the Factory only learns about the existence of classes after their modules are imported (e.g., they're registered at module import time).  So to populate the factory, I'd have to either:

1. manually import all related modules (which would really defeat the purpose of having metaclasses automatically register things...) or
2. automatically import everything in the whole project (which strikes me as incredibly clunky and ham-fisted).

Out of these options, just registering the classes directly into a factory seems like the best option.  Has anyone found a better solution that I'm just not seeing?  One option might be to automatically generate the imports required in the factory module by traversing the project files, but unless you do that with a commit-hook, you run the risk of your factory getting out of date.

### Update:

I have posted a self-answer, to close this off.  If anyone knows a good way to traverse all Python modules across nested subpackages in a way that will never hit a cycle, I will gladly accept that answer rather than this one.  The main problem I see happening is:

```
\A.py (import Sub.S2)
\Sub\S1.py (import A)
\Sub\S2.py
\Sub\S3.py (import Sub.S2)
```

When you try to import S3, it first needs to import Main (otherwise it won't know what a Sub is). At that point, it tries to import A.  While there, the `__init__.py` is called, and tries to register A.  At this point, A tries to import S1.  Since the `__init__.py` in Sub is hit, it tries to import S1, S2, and S3.  However, S1 wants to import A (which does not yet exist, as it is in the process of being imported)!  So that import fails.  You can switch how the traversal occurs (i.e., depth first rather than breadth first), but you hit the same issues.  Any insight on a good traversal approach for this would be very helpful.  A two-stage approach can probably solve it (i.e., traverse to get all module references, then import as a flat batch).  However, I am not quite sure of the best way to handle the final stage (i.e., to know when you are done traversing and then import everything).  My big restriction is that I do not want to have a super-package to deal with (i.e., an extra directory under Sub and A).  If I had that, it could kick off traversal, but everything would need to import relative to that for no good reason (i.e., all imports longer by an extra directory).  Thusfar, adding a special function call to sitecustomize.py seems like my only option (I set the root directory for the package development in that file anyway).

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to this was to do all imports on the package based off of a particular base directory and have special `__init__.py` functions for all of the ones that might have modules with classes that I'd want to have registered.  So basically, if you import any module, it first has to import the base directory and proceeds to walk every package (i.e., folder) with a similar `__init__.py` file.

The downside of this approach is that the same modules are sometimes imported multiple times, which is annoying if anyone leaves code with side effects in a module import.  However, that's bad either way.  Unfortunately, some major packages (cough, cough: Flask) have serious complaints with IDLE if you do this (IDLE just restarts, rather than doing anything).  The other downside is that because modules import each other, sometimes it attempts to import a module that it is already in the process of importing (an easily caught error, but one I'm still trying to stamp out).  It's not ideal, but it does get the job done.  Additional details on the more specific issue are attached, and if anyone can offer a better answer, I will gladly accept it.